# How to select top 20 percent of rows and then find if a row exists there

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm targeting rows like this

```
SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Date > '2015-08-13'
```

Now this works, however, im trying to find out wether a specific row exists in here but not sure on how to do this, any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: No `ORDER BY`? So you don't care which 20 percent, or that it's the same 20 percent between executions?

Comment: ye you're right, its supposed to be a order by aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CTE (common table expression) is one approach.  It forces the engine to resolve the top 20% first thereby generating a subset on which you can filter.

```
With cte as (SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Date > '2015-08-13')
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE columnName = 'Somevalue';
```

Another way is to use a inline view...  (same concept just not as clean as a CTE) and was available in engines before CTE's came into being.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
 (SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT * 
  FROM MyTable 
  WHERE MyTable.Date > '2015-08-13') inline
WHERE columnName = 'Somevalue'
```